# Algorithm for cross selling -like amazon people who bought this

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

New to this and a long time since I've done any programming or forums ....
However,  this is really getting under my skin.

I've been looking around at the algorithms used for Amazon etc on the recommendations they make around products which have an affinity to the ones people have selected - clearly this works very well.

Here is what I am wondering....

A - why would this be limited to affinity? Is there never a situation where a product would be exclusive of the original selection and perhaps a parallel but not like product might make sense?

B - why would a neural network not make sense? Could this not work well to provide a good link or would you just end up with a few product which have a very low weighting and therefore perpetuates their non selection?

Thanks for your views.

James

Comment: This is super-conceptual, even for Stack Overflow, and might belong on a different SE for conceptual questions, such as [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice I'll try these as well.

Answer (score 0):

Question A: You do not need to limit it to affinity.  However, you do need to "package up" all other pertinent information in a way that you can present it to the algorithm.  You should read up on "association rules", "frequent itemsets" & recommender algorithms.  Most of these algorithms analyze transaction data and learn rules like {peanuts, hot dogs} = {beer}. As to going away from affinity you can produce multiple sets where you reduce beer to {alcoholic beverage} then use multiple frequent item sets, at different levels of specificity, and then some sort of ensemble algorithm to combine them.

Question B: A neural network, or any other similar model would not work due to the dimensionality. Say you are Amazon.com and you want to input an item set of up to 5 items.  You might encode that as an input neuron count equal to one neuron for each item times 5.  How many items are on Amazon.  I have no idea, but I am guessing its over 100k.  Even if you get creative with dimensionality reduction, this is going to be a MASSIVE neural network, or even support vector machine or random forest.